# How Does one go about setting which column to select from for a relate field?

Tags: crm, suitecrm

What we want is that on two custom modules, when one clicks on a Reference number it shows the full details of the other module, and vice versa.

The reason is that we have a module which contains the names, address and contact of those currently leasing blocks and another module which contains the management company and charges for those blocks as well as the address of the block.

We want rather than having one giant module with all those details, to have two smaller modules that you can click through to each other.

[image: A empty record with what we want final UI to be]

Comment: Is there a reason you can just have a many to many relationship, between the two modules? As this would display as sub panels which effectively allows you to click on the related module.

Comment: Ah,  see I was trying figure that.  But the panels don't appear on listview do they?

Comment: Also I was having trouble there as I seemed to have to select each record in the subpanel rather than it autopopulating, have I missed something obvious?

Comment: m2m relationships don't show on the list view. However your screen is the detail view. So I assumed that the detail view is what you were intending to use. It is possible to use a function field in the list to get m2m relationship. You could also override the list view to change how it appears.

Comment: Regarding your auto populating issue. You can implement a after_relationship_add and after_relationship_delete logic hooks for each module and use that to relate the other module based on the criteria you need.

Comment: Well how does one set which column shows the detail view? as on accounts this is the account name which shows it, atm the behaviour suite decided is that the relate field links through to the detail view of the second module.

Comment: You can edit the panel columns in studio.

Comment: Sorry Daniel,  what I mean is, if one were to click on the words in the list view of the reference number,  it would take you through (via hyperlink) to the related field on the second module.

Comment: Is the current behaviour,  I actually don't remember how I set it up,  and I wondered how to change the hyperlink to instead go through to the detail view of the current module.

Comment: P.s, why not put one of the comments as answer,  cause I think it solved the question in the end,  I was just asking the wrong question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set up a many to many relationship, between the two modules? As this would display as sub panels which effectively allows you to click on the related module

m2m relationships don't show on the list view. However your screen is the detail view. So I assumed that the detail view is what you were intending to use. It is possible to use a function field in the list to get m2m relationship. You could also override the list view to change how it appears.

Regarding your auto populating issue. You can implement a after_relationship_add and after_relationship_delete logic hooks for each module and use that to relate the other module based on the criteria you need.

You can edit the panel columns in studio (Admin->studio). This includes which columns is a link.